# migrating svn to git and checking in to git with revision on svn

Tags: git, svn, version-control, revision-history, svn2git

I have done migrating my repos from SVN to GIT. Now developers have few changes on SVN repo. I need those changes alone to be checked in GIT by me. After cutover, I will have developers check in to GIT going.
How this can be accomplished using the revision number of SVN check-ins. 
I don't think I can use subgit tool in my infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you should do before migration is to lock the source repository for further writes. Better to lock now and restart the migrations from scratch. If the commits are already done and you cannot restart it from scratch, you can create a diff from svn and apply it on git.

To generate a git compatible patch, use --git along with `svn diff`.

`svn diff --git -r <revision(s)>`

Comment: Thanks Deepu, could you layout the steps here to create a diff. I am new to git and svn world

Comment: Thanks Dipu. But my current situation is I am not sure what the revision numbers are because multiple developers made changes in a week or so. Now can someone lay out the steps that I should take to have those specific changes made to a file be moved to gitlab(not disturbing any changes to other files on git)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But my current situation is I am not sure what the revision numbers are because multiple developers made changes in a week or so. Now can someone lay out the steps that I should take to have those specific changes made to a file be moved to gitlab(not disturbing any changes to other files on git)